# Having issue using jquery to create link tags and concatenate the href attribute to store a reult variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

To do so, I created a variable named **link** to store the link's info as follows:

`var link = '<li>' + '<a href="vote.php?id=" + result + '>' + '<b>' *text goes here* + '</b>' + </a>' + '</li>';`
`$("#lists").append(link);`

In the link's **a** tag, the href is to store a data named **id** = a variable named **result**. But that doesn't display in the address tab when I click the link, it only shows *vote.php?id=* without displaying the result variable. So please how can I handle the issue?

Notice that in the href of the link, the variable **result** is concatenated to the *id*.

Comment: Have you verified `result` actually has data and what that data is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were messing up your `'` and `"`, so were breaking / joining the String in the wrong places

```
'<a href="vote.php?id=" + result + '>'   // Wrong
'<a href="vote.php?id=' + result + '">'  // Correct
```

```js
let result = 'demo';
let placeholder = 'text goes here';

let link = '<li>' + '<a href="vote.php?id=' + result + '">' + '<b>' + placeholder + '</b>' + '</a>' + '</li>';

$("#lists").append(link);
console.log($('a').attr('href'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="lists"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following jQuery snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  var result = 1;
  var myText = "Vote 1";
  var li = $("<li>").appendTo($("#lists"));
  $("<a>", {
    href: "vote.php?id=" + result
  }).html("<b>" + myText + "</b>").appendTo(li);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lists">
</ul>
```